# An increasing function $f: \mathbb{N}_+\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{N}_+$.

Tags: functional-equations

We know that if a function $f:\mathbb{N}_+\to \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{N}_+=\{1,2,\dots,\}$ satisfies $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}_+$, then $f$ need NOT be of the form $a\log_b x$. For example, we arbitrarily assign a real number $a_p$ for each prime number $p$ and let $f(1):=0$, $f(p):=a_p$ and $f(p_1\dots p_k):=f(p_1)+\dots+f(p_k)$ for all positive intergers $k$ and prime numbers $p_1,\dots,p_k$.

What if we add a condition that $f$ is increasing, i.e. $f(x)>f(y)$ for all $x>y$ ?

Comment: Are you asking if $f$ strictly increasing and the identity $f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$ force $f(x) = a\log _b x$?

Comment: @AlvinL yeah. I know that if $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and (strictly) increasing then $f=a\log_b x$. I would like to know what would happen if $f$ is only defined on positive numbers but still be strictly increasing

Comment: @MichaelJarrett FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(xy)%3Df(x)%2Bf(y)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f%3A%5Cmathbb%7BN%7D_%2B%5Cto%20%5Cmathbb%7BR%7D%24&p=1), I found the fairly similar AoPS threads [functions with f (xy)=f (x)+f (y).](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1681559p10721183) & [Cauchy's functional equation in Z](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1335658p7225237), plus the  somewhat related [Functional Equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1628763p10218024) & post [Functional Prime Sums](/q/264318).

Comment: I think it actually forces the function to be logarithmic function. generate a sequence of rational number sequence that has a limit of $\frac{\ln p}{\ln q}$, then compare it to $\frac{f(p)}{f(q)}$ should do the work

Comment: @MafPrivate Ah, yeah. It works, thanks.